# com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException: Invalid credentials! Principal :null

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

I have configured my multi-cluster Hazelcast server on Kubernetes via the Kubernetes API discovery strategy. (Please see [Two separate hazelcast clusters in kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734960/two-separate-hazelcast-clusters-in-kubernetes)) And the members of each cluster are successfully discovering each other.

My client project is running on the k8s cluster as my Hazelcast server.
I have added the following dependency to my client project pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-kubernetes</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have configured my Hazelcast client as given in the official documentation:

```
            clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().getKubernetesConfig()
                .setEnabled(true)
                .setProperty("namespace", "default")
                .setProperty("service-name", "xyz");
```

(I have a namespace called "default" and k8s service object named "xyz")

These are the logs on client startup. Although it recognized the Hazelcast server pod, it gave an AuthenticationException (as expanded below). Also, want to point out that it did not try to connect to the correct port.

```
2019-09-18 12:59:36,699 [instance=local-service_01.devciny-dock] [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient (Slf4jFactory.java:65) - local-service_01.devciny-dock [instance_identifier] [3.11.1] A non-empty group password is configured for the Hazelcast client. Starting with Hazelcast version 3.11, clients with the same group name, but with different group passwords (that do not use authentication) will be accepted to a cluster. The group password configuration will be removed completely in a future release.
2019-09-18 12:59:36,709 [instance=local-service_01.devciny-dock] [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService (Slf4jFactory.java:65) - local-service_01.devciny-dock [instance_identifier] [3.11.1] HazelcastClient 3.11.1 (20181218 - d294f31) is STARTING
2019-09-18 12:59:36,977 [instance=local-service_01.devciny-dock] [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.integration.DiscoveryService (Slf4jFactory.java:65) - local-service_01.devciny-dock [instance_identifier] [3.11.1] Kubernetes Discovery properties: { service-dns: null, service-dns-timeout: 5, service-name: xyz, service-port: 0, service-label: null, service-label-value: true, namespace: default, resolve-not-ready-addresses: false, kubernetes-master: https://kubernetes.default.svc}
2019-09-18 12:59:36,980 [instance=local-service_01.devciny-dock] [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.integration.DiscoveryService (Slf4jFactory.java:65) - local-service_01.devciny-dock [instance_identifier] [3.11.1] Kubernetes Discovery activated resolver: ServiceEndpointResolver
2019-09-18 12:59:36,999 [instance=local-service_01.devciny-dock] [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientInvocationService (Slf4jFactory.java:65) - local-service_01.devciny-dock [instance_identifier] [3.11.1] Running with 2 response threads
2019-09-18 12:59:37,060 [instance=local-service_01.devciny-dock] [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService (Slf4jFactory.java:65) - local-service_01.devciny-dock [instance_identifier] [3.11.1] HazelcastClient 3.11.1 (20181218 - d294f31) is STARTED
2019-09-18 12:59:37,390 [instance=local-service_01.devciny-dock] [local-service_01.devciny-dock.cluster-] INFO  com.hazelcast.client.connection.ClientConnectionManager (Slf4jFactory.java:65) - local-service_01.devciny-dock [instance_identifier] [3.11.1] Trying to connect to [10.42.1.111]:5701 as owner member
2019-09-18 12:59:37,432 [instance=local-service_01.devciny-dock] [local-service_01.devciny-dock.internal-3] WARN  com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection (Slf4jFactory.java:67) - local-service_01.devciny-dock [instance_identifier] [3.11.1] ClientConnection{alive=false, connectionId=1, channel=NioChannel{/10.42.1.121:39003->/10.42.1.111:5701}, remoteEndpoint=null, lastReadTime=2019-09-18 12:59:37.426, lastWriteTime=2019-09-18 12:59:37.425, closedTime=2019-09-18 12:59:37.431, connected server version=null} closed. Reason: com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException[Invalid credentials! Principal: null]
com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException: Invalid credentials! Principal: null
        at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$AuthCallback.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:747)
        at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$AuthCallback.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:702)
        at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture$InternalDelegatingExecutionCallback.onResponse(ClientInvocationFuture.java:130)
        at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture$InternalDelegatingExecutionCallback.onResponse(ClientInvocationFuture.java:118)
        at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture$InternalDelegatingExecutionCallback.onResponse(ClientInvocationFuture.java:130)
        at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture$InternalDelegatingExecutionCallback.onResponse(ClientInvocationFuture.java:118)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:255)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
        at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
```

Comment: Are you running your Hazelcast Client  inside Kubernetes Cluster? It looks like permission problem: `connected server version=null} closed. Reason: com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException[Invalid credentials!`

Comment: Yes both the hz client and the hz server are running on the same cluster

Comment: Discovery Modes -  [Kubernetes API](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes#configuration) - `Requires setting up RoleBinding`

Comment: I have done this as well Hanx. Applied rbac.

Answer (score 0):

Your Hazelcast client tries to connect to `10.42.1.111:5701` and it find Hazelcast server there. The port looks correct and it correctly finds the Hazelcast server there.

What happens next is that it cannot authenticate with the server, which probably means that you didn't specify the cluster password in your Hazelcast configuration. You can read more on how to do it in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430267/authenticationexception-from-hazelcast-client).

Comment: I added the password as mentioned in that answer. I even set a blank password "". But this didn't help. Also, the k8s service that ive specified in the configuration is not running on 5701. This is why I feel it's incorrect in trying to connect to 5701

Comment: Then, your Hazelcast Kubernetes discovery must be wrong and tries to access the wrong Hazelcast cluster. Then, specify the port you want to use in the Hazelcast Kubernetes configuration: `<service-port>` property.

Comment: Tried that as well :p It's not recognizing this property.

Comment: You can also try to define `containerPort` on the Hazelcast Server PODs.

Comment: I have defined containerPorts as well. 
@rafal, do you think this could be a problem with rbac? I've just deployed the standard yaml given here:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes#granting-permissions-to-use-kubernetes-api

Comment: Hi @Rafal Leszko, 

I have configured my embedded Hazelcast more or less how you've described.
But I needed to connect a java client using hazelcast-client to the cluster that I had created above. 

To do this I had to define the `hazelcast-separate` Kubernetes Service as a LoadBalancer and then use the External-IP of this service in the Hazelcast Client's Network Config:
`clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(EXTERNAL-IP)`

This got the client to connect to the cluster but my question is, is this correct?
Is there another way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: @SaroshAga, I think your solution won't work for clusters with members count > 1. Check this description to find how to set up cluster with external IP: https://hazelcast.com/blog/how-to-set-up-your-own-on-premises-hazelcast-on-kubernetes/

Comment: I did have a look at this blog.

I followed the first method to connect using a Unisocket client. 
This approach also suggests connecting to the EXTERNAL-IP of the LoadBalancer service which is what I have done. 

(Also, I have tested by scaling to two pods and the Hazelcast servers running on both connected to each other. The client also seems to have connected to both members)

So is this the only way to do it?

Comment: Yes, if you exposed EACH Hazelcast member with a separate Load Balancer IP and added ALL Hazelcast members with `clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(EXTERNAL-IP)`, then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share the most important part of configuration related to client authentication. That is the group config of clusters and group config from your client. I anticipate, the problem is rooted there.

The default authentication compares group name on the member with username coming from the client. The username is filled by the client's group name (by default).

Check the [AuthenticationBaseMessageTask](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.11.1/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/impl/protocol/task/AuthenticationBaseMessageTask.java#L161-L166) code

```java
    private AuthenticationStatus authenticate(UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials) {
        GroupConfig groupConfig = nodeEngine.getConfig().getGroupConfig();
        String nodeGroupName = groupConfig.getName();
        boolean usernameMatch = nodeGroupName.equals(credentials.getUsername());
        return usernameMatch ? AuthenticationStatus.AUTHENTICATED : AuthenticationStatus.CREDENTIALS_FAILED;
    }
```

Comment: I checked my server and client config. They both have the same group config name.


Server group config:
    `    String name = groupName + "_" + environment;
        config.getGroupConfig().setName(name);`

Client group config:
`clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName(groupName + "_" + environmentName);`